# How do I use srcset and sizes in responsive HTML5 images for an image that's a percentage of it's container?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, picturefill

I'm confused by a few things in using the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes on an `img`. (I'm using [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) but it follows the original spec)

I have an image and on large screens, it's `25em` in width but on small phone-screens, it's `85%` of its container, *not* of the viewport. I do *not* want to give it a set size on smaller screens - instead I want it to adapt to its container (which is a `div`). I cannot figure out how to do this.

I also am not happy that I have to hardcode sizes and media queries into the HTML instead of putting them in CSS - it puts the same information in two places. Is there a way around this?

What I have:

```
<!--
    Is there any way to make the sizes be percentages of the container?
-->
<img 
    sizes="(min-width: 1000px) 750px, (min-width: 200px) 50vw" 
    srcset="images/full_0.png 750w, images/small_0.png 187w" 
    alt="Sizing">
```

What I want:

```
<!--
    The "use-750w" tells it which image to load but NOT the size
    to make it. Instead, it lets CSS size the image.
-->
<img 
    sizes="(min-width: 1000px) use-750w, (min-width: 200px) use-187w" 
    srcset="images/full_0.png 750w, images/small_0.png 187w" 
    alt="Sizing">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't because the HTML is separated from the CSS and the browser must know the image size before the CSS is loaded. Therefore the browser does not know the width of your `div`.

You can give [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) a try. In this case all image width must be computable before the image is loaded via CSS.